# pythonで株の予測は可能でしょうか

Tags: python3

pythonで株の予測をしたいと考えております。
必要なライブラリ等、ご存知であればご教示願います。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　ご質問が、質問の範囲が広すぎるとして改善待ちの状態になりました。このサイトでは、質問者さんだけでなく第三者が回答たちの質を把握できるように、質問をできるだけ具体的にすることが推奨されています。たとえば今回のご質問は「株の予測」に関するものですが、具体的にどのような手法で予測がしたいのかなどの情報が無いと、回答が不必要に長くなってしまいます。質問の下の「編集」から自由に追記できますので、ご質問の範囲をもっと狭めて頂けませんでしょうか。

Comment: @ クローズ投票なさった方々　何か他にも「こういう情報が必要」とお考えのものがあれば、コメントよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 必要なライブラリを教えてください。なので、お買い物質問っぽくて主観が入りそうですが、質問的には悪くないと思います。
まず質問主さんの技量が分からないのと、実装上のどこで困っているのか分かりづらいですね。
“解析するアルゴリズムは理解しているが、○○処理を行う要件を満たしたライブラリが見当たらない”とか？
あとは質問の仕方だと思いますが、１からだと「どういった機能をもったライブラリで実装できますか？」とか、
「どのようなロジック(アルゴリズム)で解析できますか？」とかがよさげなのでは？

Answer (score 3):

時系列予測をするのであれば、statsmodelsというライブラリがあります。
その他にも、ディープラーニングを使用した実装例が世の中に多くありますので、Tensorflow+KerasやChainerなどのフレームワークを検討されてはいかがでしょうか。